# GraphQL response has unwanted escape characters

Tags: java, json, graphql

My Java code receives a JSON string like this which is basically a JSON object without the structure.

```
{  "logo": "http://logo",  "name": {    "en": "AAA",    "ja": "aaa"  },  "copyrightText": {    "en": "AAA",    "ja": "aaa"  },  "help": "http://help",  "termsAndCondition": "http://terms"}
```

I have a GraphQL endpoint that wants to retrieve this string, and I want the output response to contain exactly that. But what I'm getting right now is:

```
"{  \"logo\": \"http://logo\",  \"name\": {    \"en\": \"AAA\",    \"ja\": \"aaa\"  },  \"copyrightText\": {    \"en\": \"AAA\",    \"ja\": \"aaa\"  },  \"help\": \"http://help\",  \"termsAndCondition\": \"http://terms\"}"
```

Where are these escape characters coming from? How to I get rid of them?

My GraphQL schema is as follows:

```
type Query{
    getValue: StringApiResponse
}

type StringApiResponse{
    statusCode:String!
    message:String!
    timestamp:String!
    payload:String
}
```

This is how I'm passing the string to the GraphQL from the Java code:

```
@QueryMapping(name = "getValue")
    public ApiResponse getValue(){
        try {
            String value = ValueService.getValue();
            return ApiResponse.forStatus(StatusCode.S0000)
                    .withMessage(StatusCode.S0000.getMessage())
                    .withPayload(value);
}
```

Update: It seems that the escape characters are being added by Java as it saves this variable to a String.
I couldn't find a way to get rid of them, so I'm parsing the String to JSON from the frontend using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Maybe show how you are passing this JSON String from Java to GraphQL?

Comment: To fix this issue, you can use a JSON parser to convert the JSON string into a JSON object before returning it as part of the GraphQL response. Then, the GraphQL serialization process will take care of serializing the JSON object into a string without adding any additional escape characters.
By using JSON.parse() to convert the JSON string into a JSON object before returning it as part of the GraphQL response, the serialization process will correctly serialize the JSON object into a string without adding any unwanted escape characters.

Comment: @Mojtabajalambadani I tried this.. no luck though, still getting the characters.

Answer (score 0):

As the `payload` field is declared as a `String` in the schema, as `payload:String`, and is being set with a string value in the java code, it is a JSON blob in the response, instead of a JSON object. If the type of the payload field is changed to a custom object in the schema and in the java code, it will be a JSON object in the response. The new schema could be something like below:

```
type Query {
  getValue: StringApiResponse
}

type StringApiResponse {
  statusCode: String!
  message: String!
  timestamp: String!
  payload: Payload
}

type Payload {
  logo: String!
  name: LanguageSpecificContent!
  copyrightText: LanguageSpecificContent!
  help: String!
  termsAndCondition: String!
}

type LanguageSpecificContent {
  en: String!
  ja: String!
}
```

With the above schema, we can use a query like below:

```
{
  getValue {
    payload {
        logo,
        name {
            en,
            ja
        },
        copyrightText {
            en,
            ja
        },
        help,
        termsAndCondition
    }
  }
}
```

The above query returns the below response, with payload as a JSON object instead of a JSON string:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "getValue": {
            "payload": {
                "logo": "http://logo",
                "name": {
                    "en": "AAA",
                    "ja": "aaa"
                },
                "copyrightText": {
                    "en": "AAA",
                    "ja": "aaa"
                },
                "help": "http://help",
                "termsAndCondition": "http://terms"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complete test application can be found on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/graphql-101)